# Merge two list components

Tags: list, r, merge

I have a big list, but micro example would be like the following:

```
A <- c("A", "a", "A", "a", "A")
B <- c("A", "A", "a", "a", "a")
C <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4) 
mylist <- list(A=A, B=B, C= C)
```

expected output is merge A with B so that each component will look like AB

```
AA, aA, Aa, aa, Aa
```

better should be sorted, upper case is always first

```
AA, Aa, Aa, aa, Aa
```

Thus new list or matrix should have two columns or rows:

```
AA, Aa, Aa, aa, Aa
1,   2, 3,   1, 4
```

Now I want calculate average of C based on class - "AA", "Aa", and "aa"

Looks simple but I could not figure out easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> (ab <- paste(A, B, sep="") )
[1] "AA" "aA" "Aa" "aa" "Aa"
> (ab <- paste(A, B, sep="") )  # the joining step
[1] "AA" "aA" "Aa" "aa" "Aa"
> (ab <- sub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\2\\1", ab) ) # swap lowercase uppercase
[1] "AA" "Aa" "Aa" "aa" "Aa"

> rbind(ab, C)                  # matrix
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
ab "AA" "Aa" "Aa" "aa" "Aa"
C  "1"  "2"  "3"  "1"  "4" 
> data.frame(alleles=ab, count=C)  # dataframes are lists
  alleles count
1      AA     1
2      Aa     2
3      Aa     3
4      aa     1
5      Aa     4
```

Answer (score 2):

I can do it if your data is arranged in a `data.frame` using the package `plyr`

```
> A <- c("A", "a", "A", "a", "A")
> B <- c("A", "A", "a", "a", "a")
> C <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4) 
> groups <- sort(paste(A, B, sep=""))
[1] "AA" "aA" "Aa" "aa" "Aa"
> my.df <- data.frame(A=A, B=B, C=C, group=groups)

> require(plyr)
> result <- ddply(my.df, "group", transform, group.means=mean(C))
> result[order(result$group, decreasing=TRUE),]
  A B C group group.means
5 A A 1    AA         1.0
3 A a 3    Aa         3.5
4 A a 4    Aa         3.5
2 a A 2    aA         2.0
1 a a 1    aa         1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

With your data:

```
A <- c("A", "a", "A", "a", "A")
B <- c("A", "A", "a", "a", "a")
C <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4)
```

I define a `data.frame` using the combination of A and B as the key column:

```
AB <- paste(A, B, sep='')
df <- data.frame(id=AB, C=C)

> df
  id C
1 AA 1
2 aA 2
3 Aa 3
4 aa 1
5 Aa 4
```

If you need to order this `data.frame` before the aggregation then:

```
df <- df[order(AB, decreasing=TRUE),]

> df
  id C
 1 AA 1
 3 Aa 3
 5 Aa 4
 2 aA 2
 4 aa 1
```

And with `aggregate` you calculate the mean for each `id`:

```
meanDF <- aggregate(C~id, data=df, mean)

> meanDF

  id   C
1 aa 1.0
2 aA 2.0
3 Aa 3.5
4 AA 1.0
```

But if you want to order after the aggregation, then:

```
df <- data.frame(id=AB, C=C)
meanDF <- aggregate(C~id, data=df, mean)
meanDF <- meanDF[order(meanDF$id, decreasing=TRUE),]
```